# HTML wildcard character

Tags: html, wildcard

I have images that are inserted into a jQuery slideshow. All these images are added using the *`image src`*. I was wondering if there is a wildcard character that i can use to add the images automatically rather than adding the path manually for each image.
For example:

```
<div class="frame">
            <img src="images/IMG_1.jpg" />
            <img src="images/IMG_2.jpg" />
            <img src="images/IMG_3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Is there a way i can add images automatically without having to type the source for each image or is there a way i can use wildcard character that automatically selects images with the name `IMG_*`?

Comment: Do you want to add elements, or select them with jQuery?

Comment: Yes you can do that with a `for` condition.

Comment: Can please explain how it is done with for?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your imgs named `img0.jpg` to `img4.jpg`

If you add this code, the output will be those 5 imgs.

```
<?php
  for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
    echo "<img src='imgs/img$i.jpg'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: `<div class="frame"><?php
     for ( $i = 0; $i < 8; $i++ ) {
     echo "<img src='imgs/img$i.jpg'>";
     }
   ?>
    
</div> `

Comment: I used this code but it is not working for some reason

Comment: Did you change your `page.html` to `page.php` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "wildcards" if your file names/directories follow a pattern, then you can make a loop to write them automatically instead of manually.

`./` for files in the current directory, `../` for files one directory above and `*` for all matches e.g. `<img src="../../content/images/IMG_*.*">` = all images from 2 directories above with file names starting with "IMG_" and having any file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as the browser does not know what files are there in the said source.

Best way is to number your assets, eg 001.jpg.
this way you can just use javascript to loop them using range.

Comment: Can please give an example of the script?